# Can i do math in controller before i get in blade

Tags: laravel

I need to call total monthly into my blade for another input later, I'am newbie, could controller do some math before get into blade? Because I never use MVC before.

Below is the same function of controller:-

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
    $borrow = Borrow::find($id); 

    $monthly = $borrow->total / $borrow->month;
    $interest = $borrow->total * $borrow->interest;
    $total_monthly = $monthly + $interest;

    return view('profile/detail',['profile' => $borrow]);
}
```

It will be very helpful for me if anyone suggest me the right approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some calculation or formatting of data to send to view. For this you can for `Presenters` in Laravel.

You can use below given presenter package for Laravel

```
https://github.com/laracasts/presenter
```

For the documentation you can refer [click here](https://murze.be/simplifying-presenters-in-laravel)

That is the right way to do these types of formatting or calculations of data.

It's main benefit is when you are fetching all or number of items from database using model. Then you have not need to loop that collection. you just need to create new class for that model and add present class path in your model. Then Laravel do iteration on every item of collection for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transfer calculated results using `$borrow` object, you could:

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
    $borrow = Borrow::find($id); 

    $borrow->monthly = $borrow->total / $borrow->month;
    $borrow->net_interest = $borrow->total * $borrow->interest;
    $borrow->total_monthly = $borrow->monthly + $borrow->net_interest;

    return view('profile/detail',['profile' => $borrow]);
}
```

You could also return multiple variables to blade template using array in your original code like

```
return view('profile/detail',['profile' => $borrow, 'total_monthly'=>$total_monthly, ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append data array that you are sending to view:

```
return view('profile/detail', [
    'profile' => $borrow, 
    'interest' => $interest,
    'total_monthly' => total_monthly,
]);
```

And this way all 3 variables will be accessible in view file.

One of good practical uses is to keep use of [`compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function for passing variable to view:

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id)
{
    $profile = Borrow::find($id); 

    $monthly = $profile->total / $profile->month;
    $interest = $profile->total * $profile->interest;
    $totalMonthly = $monthly + $interest;

    return view('profile/detail', compact('profile', 'monthly', 'interest', 'totalMonthly');// notice how renamed $borrow var is to correspond with compact() function
}
```